# Добавление значений при их переборе python

Tags: html, python, form, flask

У меня есть список элементов на python, который я получаю на странице `index.html` как выпадающий список и могу отправлять выбранное значение на другую страницу для обработки. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбирать не один элемент списка, а несколько сразу?

Вот весь рабочий код:

`app.py:`

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

values = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dropdown():
    return render_template('includes/index.html', values=values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`index.html:`

```
  <form action='/action' method="POST">
  <input list="myvalue" name="myvalue">
  <datalist id="myvalue" list="values">
    {% for val in values %}
        <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае отлично подошел бы [select-2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

#### Пример

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Стили для Select2 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Подключаем JQuery и Select2 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="mySelect2">
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
      <option value="MT">Montana</option>
      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="print_data()">click me</button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="myInput"></input>

    <script>
      // Инициализация Select2
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mySelect2').select2();
      });

      // Функция для кнопки
      function print_data(){
        let select_data = $('#mySelect2').select2('data');
        // Создаем новый массив для удобства
        let input_text = [];
        for (let city in select_data) {
          input_text.push(select_data[city]['id']);
          // Отображаем вычисления в myInput
          document.getElementById("myInput").value = input_text;
        }
        // console.log(select_data);
        // console.log(input_text);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Из документации

- [Возвращающие селекторы](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections):
- [Структуры данных](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats)
- [Методы](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods)

Comment: я использовал его, но почему-то при обработке этих данных, обработчик видит только одна значение, как-будто другие 9 не указаны, хотя в форме они есть

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте, это должно вам подойти

Comment: отметил как верный, можете дописать как можно сделать чтобы они сразу в `input` форму передавались?

Comment: Дополнил пример

Comment: имею ввиду без кода, просто спаисок выпадающий. чтобы из этого же инпута выпадал и в него же можно было добавлять

Comment: Не знаю чем вам помочь, вот тут простите

Comment: опечатался. без кнопки*, просто выпадающий список в инпуте с помощью `select2`. Все как у вас в примере, только чтобы в инпут записывалось все